# In pandas how to create dataframe with apparitions of certain contents?

Tags: python, pandas

In python3 and pandas I have a dataframe:

```
bancadas.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 514 entries, 0 to 513
Data columns (total 12 columns):
Parlamentar                  514 non-null object
Evangélica                   196 non-null object
Ruralista                    207 non-null object
Bala                         35 non-null object
Sindical                     43 non-null object
Direitos Humanos             24 non-null object
Mineração                    23 non-null object
Empresarial                  208 non-null object
Parentes                     238 non-null object
Saúde                        21 non-null object
Bola                         14 non-null object
Empreiteiras/construtoras    226 non-null object
dtypes: object(12)
memory usage: 24.1+ KB
```

Column "Parlamentar" has names of people. The remaining columns can have either the "nan" rows or the column name value itself. Example:

```
bancadas[['Parlamentar','Evangélica', 'Ruralista', 'Bala']].head(5).to_dict() 
{'Parlamentar': {0: 'Alberto Fraga',
  1: 'Alexandre Leite',
  2: 'Carlos Melles',
  3: 'Cláudio Cajado',
  4: 'Efraim Filho'},
 'Evangélica': {0: 'Evangélica', 1: nan, 2: 'Evangélica', 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'Ruralista': {0: 'Ruralista',
  1: 'Ruralista',
  2: 'Ruralista',
  3: 'Ruralista',
  4: 'Ruralista'},
 'Bala': {0: 'Bala', 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: 'Bala'}}
```

I need to create a new dataframe with the "source" and "target" columns, based on the dataframe bancadas

The column "source" will have the names contained in "Parlamentar". And the "target" column will have the contents of the other columns, but not the values "nan"

It would look like this:

```
source              target
Alberto Fraga       Evangélica
Alberto Fraga       Ruralista
Alberto Fraga       Bala
Alexandre Leite     Ruralista
Alexandre Leite     Empresarial
Alexandre Leite     Parentes
Alexandre Leite     Empreiteiras
Carlos Melles       Evangélica
Carlos Melles       Ruralista
Carlos Melles       Empresarial
Carlos Melles       Parentes
Carlos Melles       Empreiteiras/construtoras
...
```

So the names can be repeated in the column "source" - the number of times will be the amount of lines that do not have "nan" in the other columns

The "target" column will have each content of the other columns that corresponds to each name. Less the contents "nan"

Please, is it possible to do this in pandas? In what way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.set_index('Parlamentar')\
  .stack()\
  .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)\
  .rename('source').rename_axis('target')
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
            target      source
0    Alberto Fraga  Evangélica
1    Alberto Fraga   Ruralista
2    Alberto Fraga        Bala
3  Alexandre Leite   Ruralista
4    Carlos Melles  Evangélica
5    Carlos Melles   Ruralista
6   Cláudio Cajado   Ruralista
7     Efraim Filho   Ruralista
8     Efraim Filho        Bala
```